# BluetoothLeScanner ScanFilter on Service UUID does not work

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a simple app to scan for BLE devices, and filter the scan results down to find only my ESP32. I want to find my ESP32 by filtering on service UUIDs. I have confirmed that my custom service exists in the advertising data (via nRF Connect listing the service in "Complete list of 128-bit Service UUIDs"). However, when I add the service UUID filter as a `ScanFilter` before scanning, my `ScanCallback` is never called. I can however remove the scan filter, and manually check if the service exists in the `ScanCallback` just fine. See the below code examples.

This first example is using manual filtering, and works just fine.

```java
    private ParcelUuid mServiceUuidFilter = ParcelUuid.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");

    private final ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            boolean matched = (mServiceUuidFilter == null);
            if (mServiceUuidFilter != null && result.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids() != null) {
                for (ParcelUuid uuid : result.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids()) {
                    if (uuid.equals(mServiceUuidFilter)) {
                        matched = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (matched) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    };
    
private void scan() {
        List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();
        // works
        ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().build();
        scanFilters.add(filter);
        ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().build();

        // skipping mScanner initialization
        mScanner.startScan(scanFilters, scanSettings, mScanCallback);
}
```

This second example uses a `ScanFilter` for filtering, and does not work. `mScanCallback` is never called.

```java
    private ParcelUuid mServiceUuidFilter = ParcelUuid.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");

    private final ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            // do something
        }
    };
    
private void scan() {
        List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();
        // does not work
        ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(mServiceUuidFilter).build();
        scanFilters.add(filter);
        ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().build();

        // skipping mScanner initialization
        mScanner.startScan(scanFilters, scanSettings, mScanCallback);
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not exactly sure what I changed, but in setting my minimum API level to 21, this started working.

Answer (score 0):

The ScanFilter relies on the service UUIDs advertised by the BLE server. The ESP32 BLE library doesn't advertise services automatically, you have to do it similarly to this (where you might normally be only calling `bleServer->startAdvertising()`):

```
BLEAdvertising *ad = bleServer->getAdvertising();
ad->addServiceUUID(UUID_SERVICE);
bleServer->startAdvertising();
```

This needs to be done in addition to `bleServer->createService(UUID_SERVICE)`, which I wasn't aware of before.

Comment: I just found this answer, which is about the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66147782/3593126